# awk, print lines which start with four digits

Tags: awk

I want to print all lines from a file which begin with four digits. I tried this allredy but it does not work:

```
cat data.txt | awk --posix '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}/) print $1}'
```

No output is generated

The next line prints all lins which start with a number:

```
cat data.txt | awk --posix '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $1}'
```

Comment: Another example of a [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Print all lines that match or print the first field of all line that match?

Comment: Awk is fundamentally a pattern/action language; [understanding patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Pattern-Overview) is a fundamental skill. [Regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Patterns) are one kind of pattern. You should probably use grep instead here, but learn awk's pattern/action stuff anyway.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': Actually you do not need `awk` nor `grep`. It can be solved easily in `bash` as well.

Answer (score 7):

With awk:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ {print $1}' your_file
```

that is, check for 4 digits starting the line.

Update: 5th character not to be a digit.

```
$ awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]([^0-9].*)?$/ {print $1}' your_file
```

Note it is not necessary to use the `{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]/)` sentence, it is done with just `/^.../`.

Comment: Thank you this helps allready a bit. I forgot to mention that i needs to start with exactlly four digits. Your solution shows also >4 digits at the begining.

Comment: You might still want to consider the corner case of a line containing exactly four digits; `/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]([^0-9].*)$/...`

Answer (score 2):

For printing lines that match a given regexp `grep` is the first tool to grab:

```
grep -Eo '^[0-9]{4}[^0-9]*\s' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the problem.

```
awk --posix '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}/) print $1}'<<EOT
1234 qwer
234 asdf
34456 qwe
EOT
```

gets

```
1234
34456
```

As expected...

If You need match exactly four digits, then You could use:

```
awk --posix '$1~/^[0-9]{4}$/{print $1}'<<EOT
1234 qwer
234 asdf
34456 qwe
EOT
```

Output:

```
1234
```

But actually You do not need to run `awk` if you are in `bash`:

```
while read f rest; do
  [[ $f =~ ^[[:digit:]]{4}$ ]] && echo $f
done <<EOT
1234 qwer
234 asdf
34456 qwe
EOT
```

Output:

```
1234
```