# Awk match only when line starts with result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, debian

I have the following code:

```
function replaceappend() {
    awk -v old="$2" -v new="$3" '
        sub(old,new) { replaced=1 }
        { print }
        END { if (!replaced) print new }
    ' "$1" > /tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /tmp/tmp$$ "$1"
}

replaceappend "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" "Port" "Port 222"
```

It works perfectly but I am looking to modify it so that the awk command only finds a match if the line starts with that result. So if it's looking for the word "Port":

```
Port 123 # Test   <- It would match this one
This is a Port    <- It would not match this one
```

I've tried to look at other posts which ask about "Awk line starting with" such as this one, but I can't get my head around it:

[awk, print lines which start with four digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281583/awk-print-lines-which-start-with-four-digits)

Comment: Looks like you got your answer below, but I'd recommend looking into sed, because I believe you could do this in one line with sed. It would look something like this: `sed -i 's/^Port.*/Port 222/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. However, IIRC the -i option does not exist on BSD systems.

Comment: @LukeMat You are right about `sed` being useful.  In this case, however, Jimmy wants to use variables in the substitution command which complicates things in `sed`.  (One can substitute shell variables in `s/../../` commands but one has to be careful of shell active characters....)  Also, BSD `sed` does support `-i`.  The problem is that the BSD syntax is incompatible with the GNU `-i` version.

Comment: Well I'm proposing that there not be a function, but instead a call to `sed`, so hopefully he wouldn't have to worry about putting shell variables in there. Either way, just a possible suggestion.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestion. I actually used sed to start with but was adviced to use awk when the sed command got quite complicated. I think either one would do the job pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular expressions, `^` matches only at the beginning of a line.  Thus, to match `Port` only at the beginning of a line, write `^Port`.

For example, lets create a file;

```
$ cat >testfile
Port 123 # Test   <- It would match this one
This is a Port    <- It would not match this one
```

Apply your function:

```
$ replaceappend testfile ^Port REPLACED
```

The result:

```
$ cat testfile 
REPLACED 123 # Test   <- It would match this one
This is a Port    <- It would not match this one
```

The [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) has more information on the regular expressions supported by GNU awk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I always want to match it to the start, so can I modify the function instead? For example, do you see anything wrong with changing line two to this: ```awk -v old="^$2" -v new="$3" '```